# Regex patterns for AANNN and ANEE formats

Tags: java, regex

I need regex patterns for the `AANNN` and `ANEE` formats.

- `A` means letters
- `N` means digits
- `E` means either letters or digits.

I need to validate input strings according to these formats.

**Examples**

- `BD123` matches the `AANNN`
- `G21H` matches the `ANEE`

Comment: Ok. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Mena: but Ruby encrusted, right?

Comment: From the help center: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MitchWheat nice! Ruby and Pe(a)rl encrusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want ASCII letters and digits, but not Thai digits, Arabic letters and the like.

1. `AANNN` is `(?i)^[a-z]{2}[0-9]{3}$`
2. `ANEE` is `(?i)^[a-z][0-9][a-z0-9]{2}$`

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `[a-z]` is what's called a character class. It allows any chars between `a` and `z`.
- In a character class we can include several ranges, that's why the `E` is `[a-z0-9]`
- Normally for `A` you would have to say something like `[a-zA-Z]`, but the `(?i)` flag makes it case-insensitive
- `{2}` is a quantifier that means "match the previous expression twice
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

**How to Use**

In Java, you can do something like:

```
if (subjectString.matches("(?i)^[a-z]{2}[0-9]{3}$")) {
    // It matched!
    } 
else {  // nah, it didn't match...  }
```

Regular Expressions are Fun! I highly recommend you go learn from one of these resources.

**Resources**

- [Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075) on Stack Overflow.
- [Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- *Mastering Regular Expressions, 3rd Ed*
- *The Regular Expressions Cookbook, 2nd Ed*

Comment: Depends on the Java method the OP uses, but I would like to see anchors, otherwise you could get matches on parts of a string.

Comment: Thanks for info, i got the concept as well,surely i will go through the references to learn about regex patterns.

Comment: Thanks, glad it worked! FYI, just added some Java code. :)

Comment: FYI: reformatted your question. Have a look. IMO a question has a better chance if it is presented in a clear way like that... It got severely downvoted! See you next time. :)